# How to access firebase bucket in google cloud API

Tags: swift, firebase, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I am working on google Speech to Text API. Where i am recording audio in iphone and saving it on Firebase bucket. than when i call api i get error 403.

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json \
"https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${API_KEY}"
```

content of request.json

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "languageCode": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://audiosave-9ec73.appspot.com/AudioFiles/audio.flac"
  }
}
```

and response i am getting

> {   "error": {
>       "code": 403,
>       "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to audiosave-9ec73.appspot.com/AudioFiles/audio.flac.",
>       "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"   } }

Comment: you should use `https://` format url instead of `gs://`.

Comment: google documentation says 
"URI that points to a file that contains audio data bytes as specified in RecognitionConfig. The file must not be compressed (for example, gzip). Currently, only Google Cloud Storage URIs are supported, which must be specified in the following format: gs://bucketName/object_name"